# get access to IServiceCollection while creating IHostBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core

I created a new .NET Core project and configured the values from the appsettings.json file in the `Startup` file like so

```
private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfigurationSection myOptionsSection = configuration.GetSection("myOptions");
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(myOptionsSection);
}
```

In the `Main` method of `Program` file I want to configure the Kestrel server and want to get access to the configured options. The options provide information about the host and port the Kestrel server should listen to.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
            {
                webHostBuilder
                    .UseKestrel(kestrelServerOptions =>
                    {
                        IServiceCollection services = null; // How to get access to it?
                        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                        ReceivingOptions receivingOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<ReceivingOptions>>().Value;
                        
                        kestrelServerOptions.Listen(
                            IPAddress.Parse(receivingOptions.Host), 
                            receivingOptions.Port, 
                            builder => { /* ... */ });
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
```

The variable `services` is null because I don't know how to get access to the `IServiceCollection` here. Is there a way I can inject the `ReceivingOptions` somehow and use it for the Kestrel configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`KestrelServerOptions.ApplicationServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserveroptions.applicationservices) property. There's also the `ConfigureKestrel()` method, rather than `UseKestrel()` which you *migh*t need to change to as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the configuration by simply doing this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseKestrel((ctx, options)=>
            {
                var configuration = ctx.Configuration;
                //
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```